# OpenCV EAST Text detector implementation in Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to convert the text detection example from the below page in Java. The original code is in C++.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/text_detection.cpp

But I am facing issues in converting the below lines (131-136 in the cpp file) in Java:

```
...
    const float* scoresData = scores.ptr<float>(0, 0, y);
    const float* x0_data = geometry.ptr<float>(0, 0, y);
    const float* x1_data = geometry.ptr<float>(0, 1, y);
...
```

I tried using every method from the openCV Mat class but most of them throw exceptions!

My code till now is as below:

```
    Net net = Dnn.readNet("C:\\frozen_east_text_detection.pb");

    Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(resizedImg, 1.0, resizedImg.size(), new Scalar(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), true,
            false);
    net.setInput(blob);
    List<Mat> outs = new ArrayList<>();
    net.forward(outs, LAYER_NAMES);

    Mat scores = outs.get(0);
    Mat geometry = outs.get(1);

    int numRows = scores.size(2);
    int numCols = scores.size(3);

    List<RotatedRect> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> confidences = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.printf("numRows = %d\n", scores.size(2)); 
    System.out.printf("numCols = %d\n", scores.size(3));
```

I am not very familiar with pointers, but what I could understand is the `scores` native object seems to be a 4-D array, but it is a class in Java and there is no way in java to address a class with indices, like possible in C++ as shown, or in python as below (conversion of cpp program to python on another website):

```
for y in range(0, numRows):
    scoresData = scores[0, 0, y]
    xData0 = geometry[0, 0, y]
    xData1 = geometry[0, 1, y]
    xData2 = geometry[0, 2, y]
    xData3 = geometry[0, 3, y]
    anglesData = geometry[0, 4, y]
```

Comment: Maybe you could `reshape` those `Mat`s it to get rid of the first two dimensions? Then it would be just some simple arithmetics to calculate the right position to read from. | It does seem that the Java bindings are somewhat limited regarding `Mat`s with more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: Can you guide me a little? I am out of my depth here. What are channels, and what exactly does reshaping do?

Comment: Channels, speaking about regular `Mat` instances, would refer to the third (implicit) dimension. For example, an RGB image is considered a 2d `Mat` with 3 channels. The two dimensions are width and height, and channels corresponding to the red, green and white components.

Comment: Reshaping... the data of a `Mat` is stored in a linear array (the details of the layout are in [the C++ documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details)). There's a header which contains the information about the "shape" (size of all the dimensions) which determines how coordinates map to the underlying data array. Best to make an example... imagine you have a RGB (3 channel) image with 10 rows and 10 columns. You can reshape this into a 1 channel `Mat` with 100 rows and 3 columns. The result has each pixel from the original per row, first column is Red and so on.

Comment: I'll try to play with this tomorrow. My Java is a bit rusty tho :) BTW, could you upload that `frozen_east_text_detection.pb` file? Or provide some alternative to be able to reproduce this locally (maybe something from the OpenCV samples?)

Comment: It's a 100 mb file that I got from the below URL: https://bitbucket.org/tomhoag/opencv-text-detection/src/dbe0952752535c4d7e5cca1289a3e2118cb878dd/opencv_text_detection/?at=master . I uploaded it here just in case: https://gofile.io/?c=JkdZkN

Comment: @inquizitive I am also looking to convert the C++ program to Java. Are you making any progress on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code in Java that I found from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/berak/788da80d1dd5bade3f878210f45d6742) by [berak](https://gist.github.com/berak):

```
Mat scoresData = scores.row(y);
Mat x0Data = geometry.submat(0, height, 0, width).row(y);
Mat x1Data = geometry.submat(height, 2 * height, 0, width).row(y);
Mat x2Data = geometry.submat(2 * height, 3 * height, 0, width).row(y);
Mat x3Data = geometry.submat(3 * height, 4 * height, 0, width).row(y);
Mat anglesData = geometry.submat(4 * height, 5 * height, 0, width).row(y);
```

Here is the complete text detection code in Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.dnn.*;
import org.opencv.dnn.Dnn;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.utils.*;

public class SimpleSample {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        float scoreThresh = 0.5f;
        float nmsThresh = 0.4f;
        // Model from https://github.com/argman/EAST
        // You can find it here : https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/dnn/download_models.py#L309
        Net net = Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("c:/data/mdl/frozen_east_text_detection.pb");
        // input image
        Mat frame = Imgcodecs.imread("nantext.png");
        Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

        Size siz = new Size(320, 320);
        int W = (int)(siz.width / 4); // width of the output geometry  / score maps
        int H = (int)(siz.height / 4); // height of those. the geometry has 4, vertically stacked maps, the score one 1
        Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0,siz, new Scalar(123.68, 116.78, 103.94), true, false);
        net.setInput(blob);
        List<Mat> outs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        List<String> outNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        outNames.add("feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid");
        outNames.add("feature_fusion/concat_3");
        net.forward(outs, outNames);

        // Decode predicted bounding boxes.
        Mat scores = outs.get(0).reshape(1, H);
        // My lord and savior : http://answers.opencv.org/question/175676/javaandroid-access-4-dim-mat-planes/
        Mat geometry = outs.get(1).reshape(1, 5 * H); // don't hardcode it !
        List<Float> confidencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RotatedRect> boxesList = decode(scores, geometry, confidencesList, scoreThresh);

        // Apply non-maximum suppression procedure.
        MatOfFloat confidences = new MatOfFloat(Converters.vector_float_to_Mat(confidencesList));
        RotatedRect[] boxesArray = boxesList.toArray(new RotatedRect[0]);
        MatOfRotatedRect boxes = new MatOfRotatedRect(boxesArray);
        MatOfInt indices = new MatOfInt();
        Dnn.NMSBoxesRotated(boxes, confidences, scoreThresh, nmsThresh, indices);

        // Render detections
        Point ratio = new Point((float)frame.cols()/siz.width, (float)frame.rows()/siz.height);
        int[] indexes = indices.toArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<indexes.length;++i) {
            RotatedRect rot = boxesArray[indexes[i]];
            Point[] vertices = new Point[4];
            rot.points(vertices);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                vertices[j].x *= ratio.x;
                vertices[j].y *= ratio.y;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                Imgproc.line(frame, vertices[j], vertices[(j + 1) % 4], new Scalar(0, 0,255), 1);
            }
        }
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("out.png", frame);
    }

    private static List<RotatedRect> decode(Mat scores, Mat geometry, List<Float> confidences, float scoreThresh) {
        // size of 1 geometry plane
        int W = geometry.cols();
        int H = geometry.rows() / 5;
        //System.out.println(geometry);
        //System.out.println(scores);

        List<RotatedRect> detections = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            Mat scoresData = scores.row(y);
            Mat x0Data = geometry.submat(0, H, 0, W).row(y);
            Mat x1Data = geometry.submat(H, 2 * H, 0, W).row(y);
            Mat x2Data = geometry.submat(2 * H, 3 * H, 0, W).row(y);
            Mat x3Data = geometry.submat(3 * H, 4 * H, 0, W).row(y);
            Mat anglesData = geometry.submat(4 * H, 5 * H, 0, W).row(y);

            for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
                double score = scoresData.get(0, x)[0];
                if (score >= scoreThresh) {
                    double offsetX = x * 4.0;
                    double offsetY = y * 4.0;
                    double angle = anglesData.get(0, x)[0];
                    double cosA = Math.cos(angle);
                    double sinA = Math.sin(angle);
                    double x0 = x0Data.get(0, x)[0];
                    double x1 = x1Data.get(0, x)[0];
                    double x2 = x2Data.get(0, x)[0];
                    double x3 = x3Data.get(0, x)[0];
                    double h = x0 + x2;
                    double w = x1 + x3;
                    Point offset = new Point(offsetX + cosA * x1 + sinA * x2, offsetY - sinA * x1 + cosA * x2);
                    Point p1 = new Point(-1 * sinA * h + offset.x, -1 * cosA * h + offset.y);
                    Point p3 = new Point(-1 * cosA * w + offset.x,      sinA * w + offset.y); // original trouble here !
                    RotatedRect r = new RotatedRect(new Point(0.5 * (p1.x + p3.x), 0.5 * (p1.y + p3.y)), new Size(w, h), -1 * angle * 180 / Math.PI);
                    detections.add(r);
                    confidences.add((float) score);
                }
            }
        }
        return detections;
    }
}
```

Comment: 10x, this is helpful, this code cannot handle text that is skew, do you know if it possible with EAST, or this is a limitation?